# User-defined conditional standard local datetime format in Django

Tags: django, datetime

I have a Django project in which I have `formats.py` file for each of locales (English, French, Spanish, etc..).

The `formats.py` file looks like this:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd b Y h:i'
```

Now my goal is to define and replace `'d b Y h:i'` by a user-defined format where I get `'h:i'` for today, and `'d b Y h:i'` for dates that differ from today. Is it possible in Django ?

I have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493761/django-templates-display-a-date-only-if-its-in-the-future), but it does not help me to define STANDARD FORMAT which I could use in `formats/py`. Rather, it tells how to create a filter that I would have to explicitly apply in a template for every occurrence of datetime field.

UPDATE:

I know how to define standard datetime format in settings.py:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'android_blend.formats',
]
```

**MY QUESTION IS HOW TO DEFINE A CONDITIONAL USER DEFINED FORMAT where I have different format for today and dates other than today.**

Comment: you can mention date time standard format in setting.py file

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: Piyush, you pasted the link that I included in the question. The OP's question is different

Comment: I think you should right the function which will take the input as an user define `datetime` format(may be of today or for future date) and using `strptime` function you can mold that into required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:-

```
today =  datetime.now()

{% if inputDate == today %}
    <p>DateHeading: {{ showDate|date:"h:i" }}</p>

{% if inputDate > today %}
    <p>DateHeading: {{ showDate|date:"d b Y h:i" }}</p>
```

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, there's no django tool to make this `if-else` block place into tag to make code more DRY

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a simple template tag to format that datetime according to your needs.

Create a python folder in your app called templatetags 
Inside create a file custom_date_format.py 
Contents of which could be

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name="custom_date_format")
def custom_date_format(timestamp, user, **kwargs):
    if user.type =="option1":
         return datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    elsif user.type =="option2":
         return datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d %H")
    else:
         return datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d %m")
```

Now in your templates you can

```
{% load custom_date_form %}
{% custom_date_format datetimefield user %}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, I can't see how it is related to the question